# How can I start weeks from Monday in Custom Calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

I have to make this calendar to start weeks from monday, I used some code from Codepen but I can't change this option.
here is link of codepen: https://codepen.io/jtrumbull/pen/obPMWg

```
var Calendar = function (elem, options) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.options = $.extend({}, Calendar.DEFAULTS, options);
    this.init();
  };

  Calendar.DEFAULTS = {
    datetime: undefined,
    dayFormat: 'DDD',
    weekFormat: 'DDD',
    monthFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    weekStart: '1',
    view: undefined,
  };
  Calendar.prototype.init = function () {
    if (! this.options.datetime || this.options.datetime == 'now') {
      this.options.datetime = moment();
    }
    if (! this.options.view) {
      this.options.view = 'month';
    }
    this.initScaffold()
        .initStyle()
        .render();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to add this at the end of your code :

```
moment.updateLocale("en", { week: {
  dow: 1 // First day of week is Monday

}});
```

Here is an [update Fiddle](https://codepen.io/bilelh/pen/povQOvx)

That's following moment.js guidelines : [HERE](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/dow-doy/)